# HAProxy dynamic SSL configuration for multiple domains

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I have something like 100 similar websites in two VPS. I would like to use HAProxy to switch traffic dynamically but at the same time I would like to add an SSL certificate.

I want to use add a variable to call the specific certificate for each website.
For example:

```
frontend web-https 
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/{{domain}}.pem 
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https 
    rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000 
    default_backend website
```

I'd like also check if the SSL certificate is really available and in case it is not available then switch to HTTP with a redirect.

Is this possibile with HAProxy?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done, but TLS (SSL) does not allow you to do it the way you envision.

First, HAProxy allows you to specify a default certificate and a directory for additonal certificates.

From the [documentation for the `crt` keyword](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.1-crt)

> If a directory name is used instead of a PEM file, then all files found in
>   that directory will be loaded in alphabetic order unless their name ends with
>   '.issuer', '.ocsp' or '.sctl' (reserved extensions). This directive may be
>   specified multiple times in order to load certificates from multiple files or
>   directories. The certificates will be presented to clients who provide a
>   valid TLS Server Name Indication field matching one of their CN or alt
>   subjects.  Wildcards are supported, where a wildcard character '*' is used
>   instead of the first hostname component (eg: *.example.org matches
>   www.example.org but not www.sub.example.org).
>
> If no SNI is provided by the client or if the SSL library does not support
>   TLS extensions, or if the client provides an SNI hostname which does not
>   match any certificate, then the first loaded certificate will be presented.
>   This means that when loading certificates from a directory, it is highly
>   recommended to load the default one first as a file or to ensure that it will
>   always be the first one in the directory.

So, all you need is a directory containing each cert/chain/key in a pem file, and a modification to your configuration like this:

```
bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/my-default.pem crt /etc/haproxy/my-cert-directory
```

Note you should also add [`no-sslv3`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.1-no-sslv3).

> I want to use add a variable to call te specific certificate for each website

As noted in the documentation, if the browser sends Server Name Identification (SNI), then HAProxy will *automatically* negotiate with the browser using the appropriate certificate.

So configurable cert selection isn't necessary, but more importantly, it isn't possible.  SSL/TLS doesn't work that way (anywhere).  Until the browser successfully negotiates the secure channel, you don't know what web site the browser will be asking for, because the browser hasn't yet sent the request.

If the browser doesn't speak SNI -- a concern that should be almost entirely irrelevant any more -- or if there is no cert on file that matches the hostname presented in the SNI -- then the default certificate is used for negotiation with the browser.

> I'd like also check if the ssl is real available and in case is not available switch to http with a redirect

This is also not possible.  Remember, encryption is negotiated first, and only then is the HTTP request sent by the browser.

So, a user will never see your redirect unless they bypass the browser's security warning -- which they must necessarily see, because the hostname in the default certificate won't match the hostname the browser expects to see in the cert.

At this point, there's little point in forcing them back to http, because by bypassing the browser security warning, they have established a connection that is -- simultaneously -- untrusted yet still encrypted.  The connection is technically secure but the user has a red × in the address bar because the browser correctly believes that the certificate is invalid (due to the hostname mismatch).  But on the user's insistence at bypassing the warning, the browser still uses the invalid certificate to establish the secure channel.

If you really want to redirect even after all of this, you'll need to take a look at the [layer 5 fetches](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.4).  You'll need to verify that the `Host` header matches the SNI or the default cert, and if your certs are wildcards, you'll need to accommodate that too, but this will still only happen *after* the user bypasses the security warning.

Imagine if things were so simple that a web server without a valid certificate could hijack traffic by simply redirecting it without the browser requiring the server's certificate being valid (or deliberate action by the user to bypass the warning) and it should become apparent why your original idea not only will not work, but in fact should not work.

Note also that the certificates loaded from the configured directory are all loaded at startup.  If you need HAProxy to discover new ones or discard old ones, you need a hot restart of HAProxy (usually `sudo service haproxy reload`).